# How to rename before upload a file into server?

Tags: php

I have tried following way to upload file but file doesn't upload from my target folder, I have struggled with rename the file.. actually 'filebutton' is my input element name..

My Upload Script

```
$target_dir = "../resumes/";
                    $file_name = $cand_arrval['resume_title'].$cand_arrval['resume_name'];
                    $filename = basename($_FILES["filebutton"]["name"]);
                    $filename = $file_name . strrchr($filename, '.');
                    $target_file = $target_dir .$filename;

                $uploadOk = 1;
                echo $FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $selector = "";
                // Check if file already exists
                if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                    $uploadOk = 0;

                }
                // Check file size
                if ($_FILES["filebutton"]["size"] > 500000) {
                    $uploadOk = 0;

                }
                // Allow certain file formats
                if($FileType != "doc" && $FileType != "docx" && $FileType != "txt") {
                    $uploadOk = 0;

                }
                // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
                if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                    $prop->call_rollback();

                // if everything is ok, try to upload file
                } else {
                    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["filebutton"]["name"]);
                    $extension = end($temp);


                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filebutton"]["tmp_name"],  $target_file)) {
                        echo "<center><div class='bg bg-success text-success' style='padding:5px;'>The file <b><i>". basename( $_FILES["filebutton"]["name"]). "</i></b> has been uploaded.!</div></center>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='bg bg-danger text-warning' style='padding:5px;'>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</div>";
                    }
                }
```

`$file_name` is actually my rename text. pls if any simple way to suggest me to rename the orginal file name...

Comment: did you try `$target_file = $target_dir .$file_name;`

Comment: yes i did this way file name changed but file stored in folder `rename` but i want store with file extension `rename.docx`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add your desired file extension `.docx` when you rename the file, as long as you don't already have a folder in that location by that name.

```
$target_file = $target_dir . "$file_name.docx";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$allowed_file_types = array ('doc', 'docx', 'txt');

if (!in_array($extension, $allowed_file_types) || $_FILES["filebutton"]["size"] > 500000 ) {
$prop->call_rollback();

} else {

   .....
}
```